# C# UWP: GC (Garbage Collector) causes freezes because of InputNode QuantumStarted

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, .net-standard

For some reason the Garbage Collector in windows is triggered constantly like each 2 ~ 3 seconds and freeze the render in my app for ~half second.

I did performance profiling with VS and JetBrains and both refers to collection happens in `InputNodeQuantumStarted`

As confirmation **Yes** when I disable the audio everything works fine, specifically if I disabled the code inside `InputNodeQuantumStarted`

the code below:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("5B0D3235-4DBA-4D44-865E-8F1D0E4FD04D")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
{
  void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
}

private unsafe void InputNodeQuantumStarted(AudioFrameInputNode sender, FrameInputNodeQuantumStartedEventArgs args) {
  // Buffer size is (number of samples) * (size of each sample)
  // We choose to generate single channel (mono) audio. For multi-channel, multiply by number of channels
  uint bufferSizeElements = (uint)args.RequiredSamples * NumChannels;

  uint bufferSizeBytes = bufferSizeElements * sizeof(float);
  AudioFrame frame = new AudioFrame(bufferSizeBytes);
  using(AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Write)) {
    using(IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference()) {
      byte * dataInBytes;
      uint capacityInBytes;
      float * dataInFloat;

      // Get the buffer from the AudioFrame
      ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess) reference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacityInBytes);

      // Cast to float since the data we are generating is float
      dataInFloat = (float * ) dataInBytes;
      lock(SamplesBuffer) {
        var numElementsToCopy = Math.Min(bufferSizeElements, SamplesBuffer.Count);

        for (var i = 0; i < numElementsToCopy; i++) {
          var converted = (float) SamplesBuffer.Dequeue() / short.MaxValue;
          dataInFloat[i] = converted;
        }
        //Should we not have enough samples in buffer, set the remaing data in audio frame to zeros
        for (var i = numElementsToCopy; i < bufferSizeElements; i++) {
          dataInFloat[i] = 0f;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sender.AddFrame(frame);
}
```

As for SamplesBuffer:

```
protected Queue<short> SamplesBuffer = new Queue<short>(44100 * 4);
```

**Please note:** I already solved the problem by calling `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` constantly in-general during the render,

but I'm looking forward to solve and understand the issue so I can drop the using of `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion`

So is there anything not correct in terms of performance in the code above and how it can be better.

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/dotnet-alloc-tool?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks, my problem is I didn't found another way to do the same job, I was look for some one help to re-build the function in better way if that's possible. I don't have much knowledge and understanding in AudioGraph.